# Multiple Orders with Fake Emails. Is it Fraud?

Tags: orders, affiliate

I noticed something fishy going on with my store over the past week. We have an affiliate module setup (Affiliate Plus) on our store. Recently we've been getting a bunch of orders that are using the discount code of one particular affiliate account. They register when they checkout. Everything looks legit except the email. The addresses and CCV2s match every time, but I'm still suspicious. The monies are actually delivered via paypal to my account. I ship the orders and they (so far) are being delivered. I'm thinking about suspending the account and doing some more investigating.

Has anyone else experienced this? What are the risks associated with letting the orders continue?

Comment: Maybe you could ask the affiliate account owner about this? He might have given away his affiliate code to your buyers, right? Or maybe check the IP adresses/times when the orders are placed...

Comment: If something doesn't seem right, it probably isn't.

Comment: Any update on these orders? In general Paypal does not offer much more protection against a chargeback than normal credit card processors. If anything doesn't look quite right you need to way up if your markups can stomach a total loss or if it is better to not ship the items.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking if the transaction is handled by Paypal it's their responsibility to check for fraud. As long as you receive the money and ship the goods there shouldn't be a problem.
I would suggest contacting Paypal about this and ask them what their opinion is.

Comment: In the case of freight forwarder fraud, they can do the equivalent of a credit card chargeback. There is reason to treat even Paypal with some suspicion when things smell. Speaking from experience on the non-developer side of e-commerce here.

Comment: Even if Paypal does prevent some fraud, unfortunately at the end of the day the merchant is the one out of pocket - https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt%2Fseller%2FChargebackRisk-outside. And if there is a chargeback and you do not have a tracking number Paypal (also think virtual products) will automatically decline disputing the transaction on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what do you mean by fake email?
Do you mean your client has paid via Paypal?
we have had cases when the registered account has an email and the payment via paypal has another email account, but so far all is ok, if payment is done via paypal usually it has gone through some strict checks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the new world, cheaper to take than to make. Yes, fraud transactions are on the increase and we have seen what looks like legitimate orders, if you ask questions to the buyer they don't respond - so they are fake. If the card owner puts through a chargeback and the order was fake - you will have a fee for it, lose the products you shipped, and put your merchant account in to review.

Fraud is about prevention, most do not prevent so therein lies the problem, you have to turn down what looks to be legitimate orders - most will not do that as it affects revenue. Very simply - one fraud sale where you lose the products shipped and you need 5-10 orders to break even on it. Anyway - this is a business question which comes down to the way you process your orders so we use this instead - http://sharedvista.com/magento